# Installing Chocolatey Remotely and Get Packages Remotely

Tags: puppet, chocolatey

I am trying to install chocolatey using Jenkins to a Windows Machine that i would like to provision with some chocolatey packages.

It seems that the install log looks pretty good to me.

```
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Downloading http://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/ to C:\Users\_BUILD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Extracting C:\Users\_BUILD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to ... [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Installing chocolatey on this machine [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating ChocolateyInstall as a User Environment variable and setting it to 'C:\Chocolatey' [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: We are setting up the Chocolatey repository for NuGet packages that should be at the machine level. Think executables/application packages, not library packages. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: That is what Chocolatey NuGet goodness is for. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: The repository is set up at 'C:\Chocolatey'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: The packages themselves go to 'C:\Chocolatey\lib' (i.e. C:\Chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName). [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: A batch file for the command line goes to 'C:\Chocolatey\bin' and points to an executable in 'C:\Chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating Chocolatey NuGet folders if they do not already exist. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: d----         2/13/2013  10:20 AM            bin                                [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: d----         2/13/2013  10:20 AM            lib                                [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: d----         2/13/2013  10:20 AM            chocolateyinstall                  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Copying the contents of 'C:\Users\buildaccount\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\tools\chocolateyInstall' to 'C:\Chocolatey'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\chocolatey.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey' from anywhere. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cinst.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey install' from a shortcut of 'cinst'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cinstm.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey installmissing' from a shortcut of 'cinstm'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cup.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey update' from a shortcut of 'cup'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\clist.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey list' from a shortcut of 'clist'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cver.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey version' from a shortcut of 'cver'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cwebpi.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey webpi' from a shortcut of 'cwebpi'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cwindowsfeatures.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey windowsfeatures' from a shortcut of 'cwindowsfeatures'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\ccygwin.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey cygwin' from a shortcut of 'ccygwin'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cpython.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey python' from a shortcut of 'cpython'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cgem.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey gem' from a shortcut of 'cgem'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cpack.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey pack' from a shortcut of 'cpack'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cpush.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey push' from a shortcut of 'cpush'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Creating 'C:\Chocolatey\bin\cuninst.bat' so you can call 'chocolatey uninstall' from a shortcut of 'cuninst'. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: PATH environment variable does not have 'C:\Chocolatey\bin' in it. Adding. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing ccygwin.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cgem.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing chocolatey.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cinst.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cinstm.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing clist.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cpack.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cpush.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cpython.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cuninst.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cup.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cver.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cwebpi.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Processing cwindowsfeatures.bat to make it portable [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Chocolatey is now ready. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: You can call chocolatey from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing chocolatey. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Run chocolatey /? for a list of functions. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles first prior to using chocolatey. [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: If you are upgrading chocolatey from an older version (prior to 0.9.8.15) and don't use a custom chocolatey path, please find and delete the C:\NuGet folder after verifying that C:\Chocolatey has the same contents (minus chocolateyinstall of course). [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns: Ensuring chocolatey commands are on the path [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
[10:20:21][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Chocolatey/Exec[ChocolateyInstall]/returns:  [0m
```

However when I try to install a simple package remotely using a puppet client it complains about a .NET Framework 4.0 error.

```
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: Chocolatey (v0.9.8.20) is installing  and dependencies. By installing you accept the license for  and each dependency you are installing. [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: Execution of NuGet not detected. Please make sure you have .NET Framework 4.0 i [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: nstalled and are passing arguments to the install command. [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: At C:\Chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\functions\Run-NuGet.ps1:52 char:10 [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: +     Throw <<<<  $noExecution [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Execution of Nu...nstall comm  [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:    and.:String) [], RuntimeException [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Execution of NuGet not detected. Please make sur  [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:    e you have .NET Framework 4.0 installed and are passing arguments to the i   [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:   nstall command. [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns:   [0m
[10:20:24][Step 4/4]  [0;36mnotice: /Stage[main]/Hg/Exec[hg]/returns: executed successfully [0m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have .NET 4.0 installed on the machine?

Comment: Is that a requirement from Chocolatey?If this is a dependency inherited from nuget then i will need to change my manifest to have a dependency on net framework 4.0 installation before installing chocolatey. 

Am I correct?

Comment: I guess there is a dependency on Net Framework 4.0. I wonder if that dependency is included on the Requirements Section of the Wiki Page.

Thanks.

Comment: It is included there at the bottom. https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki

Comment: Installation of chocolatey at this time doesn't require .NET Framework 4.0. But the first time you run chocolatey you need .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  I think the Requirements section should be at the top but that is just my opinion.